# Android - nested XML pull parser issue

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I have complex XML file and I am stuck with parsing it on Android using XML Pull Parser.

```
<instances>
  <icons>
    <location>http://somelocation</location>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <size>1</size>
  </icons>
  <synthesis>
    <location>http://somelocation</location>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <size>1</size>
  </synthesis>
 </instances>
```

How to parse this nested XML file? I am fine with simple XML, but nested XML files seems to have problems when parsing them.

So far my code for parsing Icons:

```
            do {
            eventType = xpp.getEventType();
                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                    // Log.d(TAG, "start");
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    try {
                        if (xpp.getName().equals("icons")) {
                            Log.d("A", "created");
                        }
                        if (xpp.getName().equals("location")) {
                            Log.d("B", "created");
                        }
                        if (xpp.getName().equals("version")) {
                            Log.d("C", "created");
                        }
                        if (xpp.getName().equals("size")) {
                            Log.d("D", "created");
                        }


                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    }
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                    // Log.d(TAG, "Text "+xpp.getText());
                }
                eventType = xpp.next();
                //

        } while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT);
```

Thx

Hmyzak

Comment: Nobody? Really nobody?

Comment: Do you have any additional info -- is the parser failing immediately, or does it make some progress?  E.g., I notice that you have no mention of start tag "instances", but you may be handling that elsewhere. Also, this example was useful when I was working on my first pull parser: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: I have omitted start tag instance, but I need to find way, how to go deep in my XML... but thanks for XML